# How to add reference to the component in solution in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, reference, components

I have added a component in the solution in the web application in visual studio. I don't know how do I access the methods of that component from the web application. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I understand your question correctly, you need to use `using` directives and place it at the very top of your code behind file, e.g. `using MyComponent;` That way you can get reference of the available properties, methods etc from your assembly.

Comment: I have used 'using myComponent' but how can I get the method. As an example if there is a method in myComponent as avalability. How can I access it?

Comment: It depends on what methods or properties are publicly available from your myComponent assembly. What did VS say about the reference? Could you try to build your solution/project first?

Comment: I made it work. Thank you so much. You stopped me being depressed. I searched a solution everywhere for this. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

[How to: Add a Component Reference to a Visual Studio Web Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hsy826az.aspx)

> On the Website menu (for Web site projects), or the Project menu (for
>   Web application projects) choose Add Reference and then click the COM
>   tab.

[image]